# Is There A Spiceworks Equivalent?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, power-management

For some reason I vaguely recall there being an equivalent of Spiceworks for Ubuntu. I had it running on an old server that crashed and now I can't remember the name. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [description of SpiceWorks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiceworks), [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/about/) sounds a bit similar.

And Wikipedia has a longer [list of systems management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_systems_management_systems).

Of course, SpiceWorks should work on Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean by "work on Ubuntu too" is that it will scan a Ubuntu box using SSH.  The actual software itself has to run on a Windows machine (you can just use a VM if you like). Btw, I'm the community manager over at Spiceworks, for full disclosure :)